# How to use a variable to build Process.Start command?

Tags: vb.net, cmd, process.start

I'm trying to start an application through CMD using the Process.Start I currently use:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/k start C:\Windows\application.exe 127.0.0.1 8484")
```

However I want to take out the directory and replace it with a variable like so:

```
Dim line As String = C:\Windows\Application.exe
Process.Start("cmd", "/k start *line* 127.0.0.1 8484")
```

Comment: Did you try it? Did you had any problems?

Comment: @bish try what? No solutions have been posted *line* won't work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim line As String = "C:\Windows\Application.exe"
Process.Start("cmd", "/k start " & line & " 127.0.0.1 8484")
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ,`Process.Start()` will accept two string arguments, so it can be used like `"/k start " & line & " 127.0.0.1 8484"`

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim line As String = "C:\Windows\Application.exe"
Process.Start("cmd", "/k start """" """ & line & """ 127.0.0.1 8484")
```

To stay on the safe side, apply **`START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`** syntax pattern:

- enclose **`line`** in an additional pair of double quotes if it contains a blank space character, and
- [definitely use **`"title"`**](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html):

> Always include a **title**; this can be a simple string like
>   `"My Script"` or just a pair of empty quotes `""`. 
> According to
>   the Microsoft documentation, the *title* is optional, but depending on
>   the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

As per MSDN [String Data Type (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwcx436.aspx)

> *Format Requirements*
>  You must enclose a String literal within quotation marks (`"` `"`). If you must include a quotation mark as one
>   of the characters in the string, you use two contiguous quotation
>   marks (`""`)